# How to select a stringArray given an input

Tags: android, arrays

i'm learning how to do simple apps with Android.

i have a strings.xml with several array-strings. what i want is in an Android Activity to select automatically an array-string given an input string that will have the same name as an array-string in strings.xml.

my input is arraylist1, arraylist2 till arraylist20.

the names of my array-strings in my strings.xml are arraylist1, arraylist2 till arraylist20
each Array will have diferent strings.

for example i have an input my-string ="arraylist11". there is a way to refere "my-string" dinamically??

so if input is arraylist11 will get arraylist11 if the input is arraylist7 then get arraylist7 and so on.

how would be the code bellow??
"res.getStringArray(R.array.**my-string**)"

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(yourStringName, "string", getPackageName()));
```

to get your `String` but this is not recommended.

As per [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.
```